# AJAX on Rails: How to put the loaded content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view named `servicios` inside my `static_pages`, this view has a menu on the left that should load the diferent services description on click on the right `div`, I already made the AJAX call but now I don't how to put the loaded content on the page.

**app/views/static_pages/servicios.html.erb**

```
<%= provide(:title,'Servicios') %>
<% provide(:navbar,'serviciosnav') %>
<h1>Servicios</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="servicelist">
    <div class="navbar span4">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav" style="padding: 0">
            <% @servicios.each do |serv| %>
                <li><%= link_to serv.name,  "servicios/load?id="+serv.id.to_s, remote: true  %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="servicedesc" class="span8">
        <%= render partial: "servicios/load", locals: {assets: @serv = @servicios.first} %>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

**app/controllers/servicios_controller.erb**

```
class ServiciosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def load
    @serv = Servicio.first
    if !params[:id].nil?
        @serv = Servicio.find(params[:id])
    end
    respond_with(@serv) do |format|
      format.html { render partial: "servicios/load"}
    end
  end
end
```

Ans this is the Response by GET Request made to the server:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/servicios/load?id=5

304 Not Modified
        63ms    
jquery.js?body=1 (line 8435)
ParamsHeadersResponseCookies

<h2>Promoción de Inversiones</h2>
<ul>
        <li>Captación de Inversionistas en Mercados Externos.</li>
        <li>Promoción de Proyectos Industriales, Empresariales e Inmobiliarios.</li>
        <li>Intermediación en la compra ó venta de Empresas.</li>
</ul>
```

How do I update the `div#servicedesc` every time that I select something from the menu.
I have been reading all over the internet (API, forums, here) but they are all confusing and messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a nifty function called [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

With this line of jQuery code, your div will load and display whatever comes back from that controller asynchronously:

```
$('.navbar').on('click', function(){
  $('#servicedesc').load('servicios/load?id=5');
});
```

Comment: That seems easy, but the ID is not constant, and I don't want to make a Script for each button, as you see later the page will have more "servicios"

Comment: I was going for a total complicated way and totally forgot about the .load() method off jQuery, thanks to Charles for remind me of that. I just added a function in my `application.js` that has a parameter `id` and loads the desire content :)

    function loadServicio(id){
     $("#servicedesc").load("servicios/load?id="+id);
    }
And change my `link_to` on the menu to `link_to_function`

    <li><%= link_to_function serv.name,  "loadServicio("+serv.id.to_s+")"  %></li>